# CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team

Tags: python, docker-compose, pip

I'm trying to run `docker-compose` (which was installed via `pip`), yet running into following error:

```
# pip install --quiet docker-compose
# docker-compose ps
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jsonschema._types import TypeChecker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonschema/_types.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyrsistent import pmap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrsistent/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyrsistent._pmap import pmap, m, PMap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrsistent/_pmap.py", line 98
    ) from e
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#
```

---

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
9.13
# python2 --version
Python 2.7.13
# python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
#
```

Is there a way to force `docker-compose` to use python3 instead of `python` (`python2`)?

---

@Micromegas / @MikaelH

```
# apt-get -q install python3-pip
# pip3 install --quiet docker-compose
# docker-compose ps
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release ofcryptography. Please upgrade your Python.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
#
```

Comment: There is already a Debian package for docker-compose. Why not use it?

Answer (score 7):

This is the issue of the latest version(0.17.0) of pyrsistent.

You should install the past version.

```
pip uninstall pyrsistent
pip install pyrsistent==0.16.0
```

Comment: verified, it works! this looks like actual root of the issue!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will fix your problem but I hope it can help you troubleshoot. I had the same problem, but I tired to run `pip install docker-compose` in my gitlab CI.

My configs before, where the problem occured was this:

```
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add python python-dev py-pip build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev libgcc
    - pip install docker-compose
```

What fixed it for me was the following:

```
    - apk update
    - apk upgrade
    - apk add build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev libgcc
    - apk add python3
    - apk add python3-dev
    - apk add py3-pip
    - pip3 install docker-compose
```

So I guess @MikaelH's comment is spot on. Try to update to pip3 and make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed. That will depend on your environment/system. If you are on Debian you can use `sudo apt-get install python3`, `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev` etc...

Answer (score 3):

As Python 2 is now end-of-life, the Python 3 version of pip should be used to install docker-compose. On Debian or Ubuntu it can be installed with:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Afterwards the Python 3 pip version can be used to install Docker Compose

```
pip3 install docker-compose
```